# Can we create abstract class without abstract method in php?

Tags: php, class, abstract-class, abstract-methods

I want to know whether we can create an abstract class without abstract method in php or not.

If yes, then how the class is eligible to be called as 'Abstract Class' as it's not containing any abstract method? Further, is it a standard/supporting code practice?

If no, what is the reason behind it?

Can the abstract class only contain abstract methods, no more normal methods?

**Note : I want the answer with some working suitable code example. The answer should be specific to PHP language only.**

Comment: Come on. With over 1000 rep you know better than to ask questions like this

Comment: @LukeK : I didn't get any information on the internet specific to PHP in this regard, not even in the PHP manual. So, I'm asking for some help.

Comment: @LukeK Judging by the OP's profile and recent activity, you would be wrong :-)

Comment: Yes you can. It isn't eligible, just not impossible to do. I doubt it conforms to any sane standard. Why would you do this? PHP isn't designed to be bulletproof, it assumes that developers aren't insane or stupid.

Comment: @jeroen :  I didn't get any information on the internet specific to PHP in this regard, not even in the PHP manual. So, I'm asking for some help.

Comment: @user2839497 have about next time you ACTUALLY TRY WRITING CODE. Thank you.

Comment: @Mark That may be an assumption PHP should rethink… ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An abstract class is a class that cannot be instantiated and must be extended by child classes. Any abstract methods in an abstract class must be implemented by an extending child class (or it must also be abstract). It's *possible* to have an abstract class without abstract methods to be implemented; but that's not particularly useful.

The point of an abstract class is that you can define the interface in advance, but leave the implementation up to others. You can then work with that abstract interface and be sure it'll work as intended, without knowing in advance what the concrete implementation will be:

```
abstract class Foo {
    abstract public function bar();
}

function baz(Foo $foo) {
    echo $foo->bar();
}
```

`baz` can depend on what `$foo` will look like exactly, without having any idea how it's implemented exactly.

Having an abstract class without any abstract methods allows you to type hint `Foo`, but then you still don't know anything about what `$foo` will have in terms of methods or properties, so it's rather pointless.

Comment: If you've got an abstract class with just abstract methods, you should probably be using an interface.